# Can I write R+ {0} instead of 0, infinity

Tags: functions, relations

I was doing a sum and I got a dobut that can I write (0, infinity) to R+ accept {0}
This is question of range and domain

Comment: $(0,\infty)$ is the same as $\mathbb{R}_+$ if that's what you meant

Comment: I don't know what the $\{0\}$ is doing there.

Comment: Do you mean "except" rather than "accept?" If so, do you include $0$ in $\mathbb R^+?$